# How to set overflow-x with jQuery? Or: How to set css-properties with a '-' (dash)?

Tags: javascript, html, events, dom

I would like to set the `overflow-x` css property with jQuery, but it doesn't work:

```
$('.mySelector').css({
    color: 'Red',
    overflow: 'auto',
    overflow-x: 'scroll'
});
```

How would I set properties that have a '-' (dash) in them?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

You could use either camel-case:

```
$('.mySelector').css({
    color: 'Red',
    overflow: 'auto',
    overflowX: 'scroll'
});
```

Or quoted keys:

```
$('.mySelector').css({
    color: 'Red',
    overflow: 'auto',
    'overflow-x': 'scroll'
});
```

I would recommend quoted keys, I find it easier to tell 'at a glance' what a rule is compared to camel-casing.

Comment: Could I set all '-' properties like this?

Comment: Why did you edit your answer, your original answer with overflowX worked very good :-)

Comment: @Kess, sorry, I'm on a very slow connection and was in the middle of researching my answer in order to make sure it was as accurate as possible

Answer (score 2):

You can quote it (with single or double quotes) or use the camel case variant (which the DOM adopted with its `style` object, because `-` are not legal in identifiers).

```
$('.mySelector').css({
    'color': 'Red',
    'overflow': 'auto',
    'overflow-x': 'scroll'
});
```

Comment: Could I set all '-' properties like this?

Comment: Can I combine non-quoted and quoted, like `{ color: 'Red', 'overflow-x': 'scroll' }`?